# Weird swift interpolation error: Could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolationSegment'

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, events, swift

I get a weird error when I try to use swift's interpolation in the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Clicked!",
                                      message:"You clicked row # \(indexPath.row)",
                                      preferredStyle: UIAlertViewStyle.Default);
    }
```

I haven't finished the alert view yet, but I don't think thats the cause of the error. Its happening at the message parameter.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Try creating a constant for the message and then using that constant in the initialization. That might help make the error clearer, or at least ensure the message really is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You chose the wrong `enum` value there. Issue is with this code:

```
UIAlertViewStyle.Default
```

Change that to:

```
UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
```

`UIAlertViewStyle.Default` is used for specifying the button styles of `UIAlertview` and `UIActionSheet`.

Reference [**UIAlertControllerStyle**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIAlertControllerStyle)

> #### **UIAlertControllerStyle**
>
> Constants indicating the type of alert to display.
>
> ***ActionSheet***
> An action sheet displayed in the context of the view controller that presented it.
> Use an action sheet to present the user with a set of alternatives for how to proceed with a given task. You can also use this style to
> prompt the user to confirm a potentially dangerous action.
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
>
> ***Alert***
>
> An alert displayed modally for the app.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Reference [**UIAlertActionStyle**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertAction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIAlertActionStyle)

> #### **UIAlertActionStyle**
>
> Styles to apply to action buttons in an alert. Declaration Constants
>
> ***Default***
> Apply the default style to the action’s button.
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
>
> ***Cancel***
> Apply a style that indicates the action cancels the operation and leaves things unchanged.
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
>
> ***Destructive***
> Apply a style that indicates the action might change or delete data.
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working fine for me:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Clicked!", message: "You clicked row # \(indexPath.row)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

replace your code with this.